# Stack Exchange dropdown list, Inbox and Achievement dialogs are not working in the stackexchange.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

The Stack Exchange dropdown list which is in the left hand side top of the header is not working in the https://stackexchange.com site.

The Inbox and Achievement dialog boxes are also not responding.

[image: Dropdownlist not working]